# Oracle equaivalent of java System.currentTimeMillis()?

Tags: oracle, time

I want to be able to store the current time in milliseconds in an Oracle number field. How do I do this via a query?

```
select systimestamp from dual;
```

returns the actual timestamp. Is there anyway that I can convert this into milliseconds the same way Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` does?

Comment: Some useful suggestions here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_timestamp_math_elapsed_times.htm

Answer (score 12):

The Java function returns the number of milliseconds which have elapsed since a fixed moment in time.  That time is midnight on the first day of 1970 UTC, i.e. the start of Unix clock time.

The following function does the same for PL/SQL.  It subtracts the current timestamp from the starting point (where ms=1).  It extracts the various time components and turns them into seconds.  Finally it multiplies everything by 1000 to get the value in milliseconds:

```
create or replace function current_millisecs 
    return number 
is
    base_point constant timestamp := to_timestamp('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00.000');
    now constant timestamp := systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ;
begin
    return (
                  ((extract(day    from (now-base_point)))*86400)
                + ((extract(hour   from (now-base_point)))*3600)
                + ((extract(minute from (now-base_point)))*60)
                + ((extract(second from (now-base_point))))
           ) * 1000;
end;
/
```

If you have Java enabled in the database you may find it simpler to create a Java Stored Procedure instead:

```
create or replace function currentTimeMillis return number as
language java name 'java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() return java.lang.Integer';
/
```

Comparison of the two approaches:

```
SQL> select currentTimeMillis as JAVA
  2         , current_millisecs as PLSQL
  3         , currentTimeMillis - current_millisecs as DIFF
  4  from dual
  5  /

      JAVA      PLSQL       DIFF
---------- ---------- ----------
1.2738E+12 1.2738E+12          0

SQL>
```

(My thanks go to Simon Nickerson, who spotted the typo in the previous version of my PL/SQL function which produced an anomalous result.)

---

Incidentally, if you are only interested in time to the nearest centisecond, Oracle has a built-in for that: [DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1002765).

Comment: There are 3600 seconds in an hour, not 3660.

Comment: @SimonNickerson - Ah, that would explain it!  Thanks.

Comment: depending on your settings, you may need to create the base_point timestamp as follow:
  to_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')

Comment: this worked for me very well, I only stumbled upon `to_timestamp('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00.000');` ORA-01849 hour must be between 1 to 12. It is fixed by using: `to_timestamp_tz('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00.000+00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';`

Answer (score 5):

this link helps for all languages
[currentmillis.com](http://currentmillis.com/)
for oracle:

```
SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Incorrect answer as it does not take the current timezone into account.

Comment: current timezone is taken into account in SYSDATE. it works correctly

Comment: Within a few seconds of each other: Current Time Millis as per https://currenttimemillis.com: 1489491379553
Current Time Millis as per the method above : 1489529163000
Difference: 37891447

Answer (score 3):

- DB timezone agnostic
- with milliseconds
- works in XE

```
    function current_time_ms
        return number
    is
        out_result number;
    begin
        select extract(day from(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) - to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) * 86400000 
            + to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp), 'SSSSSFF3'))
        into out_result
        from dual;
        return out_result;
    end current_time_ms;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

select extract(day from(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'GMT') - to_timestamp('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) * 86400000
+ to_number(to_char(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'), 'SSSSSFF3'))
from dual;