# Oracle equivalent for java's System.nanoTime()

Tags: java, oracle

Is there any equivalent for java's "System.nanoTime()" in oracle? 
In java System.nanoTime() returns something like "246193102011083".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824710/oracle-equaivalent-of-java-system-currenttimemillis

Comment: You might be able to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826515/180100 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318211/180100

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible?

Comment: What are you trying to use it for? `System.nanoTime()` is not a general purpose method. It's only usable for measuring duration between 2 nanotimes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP(9) FROM DUAL;
```

*Note - in testing on a Solaris box I could only see micro-second precision; the last 3 digits of the timestamp always appeared to be `000`. On a Windows box, i could only see milli-second precision so the accuracy you get may be dependent on the OS (or other factors).*

If you want it as nano-seconds from an epoch (e.g. 1970-01-01) then:

```
SELECT   EXTRACT( DAY    FROM time ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1e9
       + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM time )      * 60 * 60 * 1e9
       + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM time )           * 60 * 1e9
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM time )                * 1e9 AS nanotime
FROM ( SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP(9) - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AS time FROM DUAL );
```

You could also use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nanotime RETURN NUMBER
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'java.lang.System.nanoTime() return long';
/

SELECT nanotime() FROM DUAL;
```

*Note - Both Solaris and Windows both appear to give micro-second precision when I tested it.*

Comment: But every time I see triple zeros at the end. Does this mean that it is only having microsecond precision? eg: "1505470076941452000"

Comment: Evidently just microseconds.

Comment: nanoTime is not clock time, rather a checkpoint with nano precision which is to be used with another call to nano to measure the displacement between two points in code execution.